# Materialize CSS Navbar Search is broken

Tags: css, html, material-design, frontend, materialize

Navbar search is broken on chrome 50+ using either of these versions:

materialize 0.97.6
materialize 0.97.5

Code used is as described in the documentation:

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <form>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input id="search" type="search" required>
          <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

this code leads to visual issues as depicted on the documentation page as well as my site:

http://materializecss.com/navbar.html

[image: broken search]

[image: broken search on my site]

How do i fix this to make it look uniform?

Comment: Are you referring to the one on materializecss.com? Looks fine to me.

Comment: What version of materializeCSS are you using? Post your current code to try and reproduce the error. Please learn how to post a useful question on stackOverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sami -- are you on chrome 50+ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright I was having the same issue. However, I added this CSS and it worked for me.

```
nav .nav-wrapper form, nav .nav-wrapper form .input-field{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this fixed it for me too though I went with a static px height .. for both my nav search bars -- one smaller one in the header and one larger one on the main page.

funny I solved it and then remembered i should check the StackOverflow answers :)

Comment: Awesome Happy Coding!

Answer (score 11):

I just noticed this today and I just did this:

```
input[type="search"] {
  height: 64px !important; /* or height of nav */
}
```